# How to deploy the heroku nginx buildpack using the new buildpacks.io framework?

Tags: shell, nginx, heroku, buildpack

I am following this tutorial to deploy a custom heroku buildpack for nginx:

http://jkutner.github.io/2020/05/26/cloud-native-buildpacks-shim.html

When I deploy the original heroku nginx buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx

After using pack to compile and build it, the following error is thrown:

```
cp: 'bin/start-nginx' and '/workspace/bin/start-nginx' are the same file
```

This is how the compile script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

# clean up leaking environment
unset GIT_DIR

# parse and derive params
BUILD_DIR=my_nginx
CACHE_DIR=$2
BUILDPACK_DIR="$(dirname "$(dirname "$0")")"

mkdir -p "$BUILD_DIR/bin/"
mkdir -p "$BUILD_DIR/nginx"
tar -zxvf "nginx-$STACK".tgz -C "$BUILD_DIR/nginx"

cp "$BUILD_DIR/nginx/nginx" "$BUILD_DIR/bin/nginx"
cp "$BUILD_DIR/nginx/nginx-debug" "$BUILD_DIR/bin/nginx-debug"

nginx_version=$($BUILD_DIR/bin/nginx -V 2>&1 | head -1 | awk '{ print $NF }')
echo "-----> nginx-buildpack: Installed ${nginx_version} to app/bin"
cp bin/start-nginx "$BUILD_DIR/bin/"
echo '-----> nginx-buildpack: Added start-nginx to app/bin'
cp bin/start-nginx-debug "$BUILD_DIR/bin/"
echo '-----> nginx-buildpack: Added start-nginx-debug to app/bin'
cp bin/start-nginx-solo "$BUILD_DIR/bin/"
echo '-----> nginx-buildpack: Added start-nginx-solo to app/bin'

mkdir -p "$BUILD_DIR/config"

if [[ ! -f $BUILD_DIR/config/mime.types ]]; then
        cp "$BUILD_DIR/nginx/mime.types" "$BUILD_DIR/config/"
        echo '-----> nginx-buildpack: Default mime.types copied to app/config/'
else
        echo '-----> nginx-buildpack: Custom mime.types found in app/config.'
fi

if [[ ! -f $BUILD_DIR/config/nginx.conf.erb ]]; then
        cp config/nginx.conf.erb "$BUILD_DIR/config/"
        echo '-----> nginx-buildpack: Default config copied to app/config.'
else
        echo '-----> nginx-buildpack: Custom config found in app/config.'
fi

# cleanup
rm -r "$BUILD_DIR/nginx"

exit 0
```

Is this buildpack broken , where can I find a proper nginx buildpack to use since the heroku one causes these issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the article given below and take help from it. Also, I am providing the link to the Heroku-Nginx pack which is the most preferable one.

Article : https://koed00.github.io/Heroku_setups/

Pack:  https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx

Comment: Hey, thanks for providing an answer to this question! Please include what to do here on Stack Overflow and have the links you provided for sources and/or additional reading material.